# merge same name columns during json conversion in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like this:

```
    question option option
1   "1+2 ?"      1     3
```

And I want to convert it to json

```json
{"question":"1+3 ?", "option": [1,3]}
```

I know data can be converted to json using `df.to_json(orient='records')` but first there has to be an Options column with option grouped together for example as csv or array.

How do I achieve the following (some_function_that_gets_Option_as_array) given that there can be any number of options?

```py
df["Options"] = df.some_function_that_gets_Option_as_array()`
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: is it better @AMC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new column with the the values in your `option` columns and export using `to_dict` with `orient="records"`:

```
print (df.assign(opt=df.filter(like="option").values.tolist())
         .loc[:, ["question","opt"]].to_dict(orient="records"))

#
[{'question': '"1+2 ?"', 'opt': [1, 3]}]
```

Comment: Thanks ! A slight modification will be better, using `.drop(['option'], axis = 1)` instead of `.loc` so that if there are several other columns they don't need to be rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'question': ["1+2 ?"], 'option': [1],  'option_':[3]})
df['c'] = df[['option', 'option_']].apply(lambda x: list(x.astype(str)), axis=1)
df.drop(['option', 'option_'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.to_json(orient='records')[1:-1].replace('},{', '} {')
```

Output:

```
{"question":"1+2 ?","c":["1","3"]}
```